# jQuery class applies when clicked on parent, but not when clicked on child

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have this function that triggers when clicked on.

```
$('.projectsTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
  $(this).addClass('activ').siblings().removeClass('activ');
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover projectsTable">
    <tr ng-repeat="projects in ctrl.tabs" class="clickable-row">
        <td ng-click="ctrl.tab = projects.title">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-6">
                {{projects.name}}
                <br><br>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-6" >
                <uib-progressbar animate="false" value="projects.thingy * 10" type="success" ng-if="ctrl.tab != projects.title" >{{projects.thingy * 10}}</uib-progressbar>
             </div>
           </div>          
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

When I click on anywhere on the table element, the function triggers and the class gets applied correctly. But when I click on the `uib-progressbar`, the function does not get triggered.

Any idea why this happens? I'm quite new to jQuery.

Comment: `uib-progressbar` may be stopping the propagation of the `click` event. In that case, you would have to modify that component.

Comment: or simply capture click event instead

Comment: @A.Wolff I have added `console.log(this)` to the function and it correctly shows me the HTML code, but when I click on the `uib-progressbar`, nothing appears.

Comment: @A.Wolff, true, didn't think of that. Registering a handler for the capture phase would work.

Comment: So as mentioned before, it seems that "uib-progressbar" is stopping the propagation of the click.

Comment: Like Frédéric said, this component (which i don't know) may be stopping click event propagation. Again, if it is the case, you could capture click event instead: `document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 var $clickableRow = $(e.target).closest('.projectsTable .clickable-row');
 $clickableRow.addClass('activ').siblings().removeClass('activ');
}, true);`

Comment: @A.Wolff That worked. Thank you :)

Comment: @JonSummer Just be aware than IE8 doesn't support capturing phase. If you need to support it, you need to investigate why the click propagation is stopped. You could force it by simulate parent click